# Far Cry 4 on Windows 8.1: "This app can't run on your PC"

Tags: windows-8.1, compatibility, gaming

I just installed *Far Cry 4*, but when I try to run the .exe file it says "This app can't run on your PC". What is the reason for this?

My system specifications:

- Intel Core 2 Duo processor, 2.8 GHz
- 4 GB RAM
- 32-bit operating system, x64-based processor.

Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 x86 is installed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does Far Cry 4 say are the system requirements?  What is your graphics card?

Comment: Requirements :

1) Windows 8.1 (Which I have)
2) Intel Core i5 2.6 GHz (Hmm mine is 2.8)
3) AMD Radeon HD5850 (Mine is AMD Radeon HD 7700 Series)

Hope this helps.

Comment: What is an "Inter Core 2 Processor"? Please be more specific. Do you mean Intel? A Core 2 Duo, perhaps? Either way that'd be too low in specs.

Comment: You don't meet the CPU requirements. A Core 2 Duo at 2.8GHz is vastly inferior to even the slowest Core i5 at 2.6GHz.

Comment: As others have suggested your processor doesn't even begin to meet the requirements.  Even if you were running a 64-bit version of Windows the game wouldn't be playable on your machine.

Answer (score 3):

Your computer has a 32-bit OS installed, but ***Far Cry 4* requires a 64-bit system** (some emphasis added):

> Today Ubisoft released the PC specs for Far Cry 4. Below are the system requirements in full.
>
> ### Minimum
>
> - **Supported OS:** Windows 7 SP1, Windows 8/8.1 (**64bit versions only**)
> - [...]
>
> —*Ubisoft official blog ([source](http://blog.ubi.com/far-cry-4-pc-specs/))*

Even if you install 64-bit Windows, you probably won't get a playable experience because your hardware isn't quite up to the level expected by today's games. Your video card seems to be marginal at best, and your processor probably can't keep up. You should consider upgrading your computer if you want to play modern games of this kind.